# Trying to understand Hanoi algorithm using my own program

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I have the following working program for tower of Hanoi where we will move disks from A--B tower and C is the extra tower.I defined the initial state of the function as follows:     `moveDisks(n, 'A', 'B', 'C');`

I will print each time I make a move using the following algorithm:

```
public static void moveDisks(
        int n,
        char fromTower,
        char toTower,
        char auxTower)
    {
        if (n == 1) // Stopping condition
            System.out.println(
                "Move disk " + n + " from " + fromTower + " to " + toTower);
        else
        {
            moveDisks(n - 1, fromTower, auxTower, toTower);
            System.out.println(
                "Move disk " + n + " from " + fromTower + " to " + toTower);
            moveDisks(n - 1, auxTower, toTower, fromTower);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the recursive calls in my program, I have three possible calls:

```
    A--B--C //fromTower, toTower,auxTower
    A--C--B //fromTower, auxTower, toTower
    C--B--A //auxTower, toTower, fromTower
```

However, I'm getting the following printouts for `3` disks:

```
The moves are:
Move disk 1 from A to B
Move disk 2 from A to C
Move disk 1 from B to C
Move disk 3 from A to B
Move disk 1 from C to A
Move disk 2 from C to B
Move disk 1 from A to B
```

I know my program is correct but I'm not really getting how it's doing `B--C`  and `C--A` calls because I never made such function/method.I would appreciate if you can show how this recursive method is working in terms of three disks using my `A--B--C`, `fromTower, toTower,auxTower` model.

Comment: Run it with a debugger to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: the debug saying me it's already running.How do I debug an already running program?@pjs

Comment: Since I have no idea which IDE you're using, I can't advise on that.  Most debuggers will have a mechanism for setting breakpoints, and a way to step through your code line by line with the ability to inspect the variables.  You're on your own for the details of doing so in your IDE.

Comment: I'm using eclipse, professor. @pjs

Comment: If you wrote that program, I can't believe that you don't understant how the tower names are interchanged.

Comment: So what's the surprise there are moves from A to C and C to B ???

Comment: A--B--C //fromTower, toTower,auxTower
    A--C--B //fromTower, auxTower, toTower
    C--B--A //auxTower, toTower, fromTower

Comment: Mh, "Introduction to Java Programming, 20.7 Problem: Tower of Hanoi, p. 691."

Comment: I never said otherwise so how I'm getting them?Is there recursion for each of those that will continue separately?

Comment: So? I'm still trying to understand.@YvesDaoust

Comment: @YvesDaoust I figured it at last!Feeling so good!

Comment: @SittingBull: that's the magic of recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out this myself at last.I can see that it's amazingly following binary tree structure, calling the left most child first(in this case a child is a print statement) in the recursion.

The mistake that I had in my understanding was that, I assumed `A--B--C` as `from-to-aux` for all recursive calls, although the `from-to-aux` variables have been changing throughout.So when I start with `n=3` and `A= from,B=to, C= aux`, I get the following calls: `moveDisks(2, 'A', 'C', 'B')` and `moveDisks(2, 'C', 'B', 'A')`.Now each of these recursive calls will independently start their own calls but for the first one now `A=from, C=to, and B=aux` and the second one `C=from, B=to and A=aux`.So for the first one I get `moveDisks(1,'A','B','C')` and `moveDisks(1,'B','C','A')` calls and the second one I get `moveDisks(1,'C','A','B')` and `moveDisks(1,'A','B','C')` calls.Recurssion continues till it reaches the stopping point.

---

[image]

**Note:** This is so amazing!I was learning recursion but ended up learning binary tree as well!

Answer (score 0):

You are considering the possible calls to `moveDisks` only from the perspective of the initial call:

```
moveDisks(.., 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

will call

```
moveDisks(.., 'A', 'C', 'B')
moveDisks(.., 'C', 'B', 'A')
```

but the recursion will continue for these calls and thus the next rounds of calls will be

```
moveDisks(.., 'A', 'B', 'C')
moveDisks(.., 'B', 'C', 'A')  --> moving B to C
```

and

```
moveDisks(.., 'C', 'A', 'B')
moveDisks(.., 'A', 'B', 'C')
```

...